# zeta-function vs. riemann-zeta tags

Tags: discussion, tag-management

The tag "zeta-function" seems to have been made synonomous with "riemann-zeta".

This came up in the comments section of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45851/when-functions-analytically-continued-carry-over-certain-properties).

Perhaps this should be reconsidered.  There are other zeta-functions 
besides Riemann's.  (Apart from other zeta-functions occuring in number-theory/arithmetic geometry, there are also Selberg zeta-functions, various
dynamical zeta-functions, and so on.)

What do people think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags have been un-synonymized and I've renamed [zeta-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeta-function) to [zeta-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeta-functions).

Comment: @Qiachou: Dear Qiaochu,  Thanks for this!  Best wishes,

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with keeping zeta-function and riemann-zeta synonymous, while having another tag zeta-functions for those posts about one or more zeta functions other than Riemann's.

Comment: I think having both [zeta-function] and [zeta-functions] is mildly confusing and I don't completely trust the average user to make that distinction...

Comment: **Ideally** someone (perhaps @Matt) would be so kind as to [write a Tag Wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/965) (or just a short blurb) to help disambiguate! `:)`

Comment: @Gerry: Dear Gerry, I agree with Qiaochu that it would be confusing to have [zeta-function] and [zeta-functions] as different tags.  I agree that the current set-up (i.e. having the tags [zeta-functions] and [Riemann-zeta]) *will* lead to people posting questions about Riemann zeta with the more general tag [zeta-functions] (which I guess was the reason for the merge in the first place), but I don't know what the best solutions is.  Perhaps writing Tag Wiki's as Willie suggests.  Regards,

Comment: @Willie: Dear Willie, Thanks for the kind invitation!  I'll try to do this.  Best wishes,